# Generator Expression, access iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, generator-expression

I'm trying to `escape` items in a list by checking them against another list of items.
I can filter the list:

```
@staticmethod
def escapeFrameData(frameData):
  toEscape = [0x7e, 0x7d, 0x11, 0x13]

  genExpr = (x for x in frameData if x in toEscape)
  for x in genExpr:
    print x
```

Now I'd like to put the escape character in front of each item found. Something like this:

```
genExpr = (x for i, x in frameData if x in enumerate(toEscape))

for x in genExpr:
  frameData.insert(i-1, 0x7d)
return frameData
```

#### Needed behaviour:

```
frameData = [0x02, 0x7e, 0x04]
escaped = class.escapeFrameData(frameData)
escaped is now: [0x02, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x04]
```

How would the generator expression have to be written to accomplish this? Is there a better way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a really slow way to go about solving this problem.  A better approach, assuming these are bytes (it looks like they are) would be to use byte strings and the `re` module.  For instance, you might write

```
re.sub(r'[\x7e\x7d\x11\x13]', b'\x7d\\1', frameData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator *function* instead:

```
@staticmethod
def escapeFrameData(frameData):
    toEscape = {0x7e, 0x7d, 0x11, 0x13}
    for x in frameData:
        if x in toEscape:
            yield 0x7d
        yield x
```

I replaced your list of to-escape values with a set for faster lookups.

You'd call `list()` on the function:

```
escaped = list(class.escapeFrameData(frameData))
```

or just loop over the generator.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is using a set and then casting it back to a list really that much faster? I'm probably going with the regex solution but that info can come in handy one day. ps: I really should read up on data types and python in general.

Comment: @simp: You are not casting the set back to a list, you are collecting the generator output back into a list. The `set` is only used for `toEscape` because you use `if x in toEscape` in a loop.

Comment: @simp: Your own code used a generator expression, then only *prints* the values yielded; I was assuming that you really wanted the function to return a generator instead.

Comment: @simp: last but not least, using a generator function here made it trivial to conditionally inject extra values into the output.